Weird phenomenon when parsing xsd file in python (specifically with line numbers/reference)

I am parsing an XSD file and there is a weird phenomenon happening when I am parsing. I have this element for example:
<xsd:element name="Example" type="ExampleType" minOccurs="0">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            <Description>This is the description</Description>
            <LineNumber>4</LineNumber>
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>

And I am using this code:
#xml.etree.ElementTree
annotation = element.find(".//xsd:annotation", namespace)
if annotation is not None:
   documentation = annotation.find(".//xsd:documentation", namespace)
   if documentation is not None:
       for doc_child in documentation:
           tag = doc_child.tag.split('}')[-1] 
           element_dict[element_name][tag] = doc_child.text.strip() 

Now here is the weird part. Once I convert the element_dict to a dataframe and the dataframe to an excel the line number changes. I am taking both the description and the line number and if I where to print out in the example it would be:
Description: This is the description
LineNumber: 4

But in the excel file it comes out like this
Description: This is the description
LineNumber: Part A Line 12

I have confirmed that this element is pulling from Part A Line 12 (a later element in the xsd), but I am very confused on what in the code is causing this? Also how would I parse it so I can get both the  and this reference line number?

Alright so I figured it out. Turns out what was happening was that when I was pulling the data there were two elements with the exact same name (ExampleName).
Since I was adding this data to a dictionary where the element name was the key I had two elements updating the same record.
{
   "Name" : "ExampleName",
   "LineNumber" : "4"
}
{
   "Name" : "ExampleName",
   "LineNumber" : "Part A Line 12"
}

First the LineNumber "4" then set to "Part A Line 12"
